# Do 2-aminoalkanes undergo iodoform test?

Tags: halides

I was doing problems in an excercise book and they gave a list of compounds that may undergo iodoform test- which included 2-aminoalkanes.
I dont find any keto methyl gps or methyl carbinol gps that would give iodoform test that normally would give the test. Can someone shed some light here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the mechanism for iodoform test given by 2-Aminoalkanes?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/95524/what-is-the-mechanism-for-iodoform-test-given-by-2-aminoalkanes)